# Using generic (custom) connections with Auth0

Tags: oauth, tumblr, auth0

I am trying to use Auth0 to log in to several social media sites at once in a single page app. I have added a generic OAuth2 server to my account for Tumblr, using the instructions here: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/oauth2. I have verified that the server was correctly added, and the JSON-P response for my client application is populated with the correct info based on what I added.

My question is, how can I use the JS popup widget to login to this server? I essentially have a couple social logins that are built-in to Auth0 that are working by passing (e.g.) `connections: ['twitter']` to the `.show()` function, and a couple social logins that are not built-in, that I can't seem to wire in correctly to work similarly to the built-in social logins.

In other words, when I use `connections: ['twitter']`, the popup correctly shows the "Login with Twitter" button. However, when I use `connections: ['tumblr']` (where 'tumblr' is the name of the custom connection I made), the popup doesn't show any buttons or even the username/password fields to login to my custom connection. I'm clearly not understanding how this popup is supposed to work with custom connections, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Tumblr uses `oauth1`, not `oauth2`. So, I was on the right track, but I was just using the wrong eaxmple page. Here is the example page for oauth1 connections: https://auth0.com/docs/oauth1.

You can also then add customizations to the login screen as described here: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/ui-customization. That will allow you to do what I was looking for in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Custom OAuth2 connections won't show up on Lock (the UI widget), you have to use your own UI. The library you are looking for is auth0.js (UI-less library) that will handle the auth process for you.

> This is likely changing in the next release of Lock.